# Does money affect the ending?

Tags: luigis-mansion-dark-moon

Does the amount of capital I raise in *Luigi's Mansion: Dark Moon* affect the ending I will receive? Or will it affect anything other than getting the last upgrade at 20,000 gold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: **No.**

Total coins are only for upgrades. Per level coins are only for star ranks.